# Potentially upload huge amount of images

Tags: file, upload, limit, store

i m working on a web app, which potentially has unknown number of image uploads. The structure is something like: busines--products--images. One business can have lots of products, and each product can have 3 to 50 images. The system is open to everyone to register and create business, so when there are 10k businesses with 10 products per business, and 10 images per product, there will be 1 million images uploaded to the server.

My question is how should these images to be stored on the server. I know there's a limit in Linux, what i normally did is to split the filename or a specific string in certain pattern to spread the files into a hierarchical structure hence each folder contains small amount of files. The good side about this is it solves the file limit issue and fast to retrieve a file; on the other hand this method could use too many iNodes while the file amount increases.

Can anyone help me with this, how does a web server stores large number of uploaded files? I m not sure if the application will be deployed on a Linux server or a Windows one, please let me know how you do!

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: I figured out a way, which is the same as my old method. i use business_create_date/business_id/product_id/images... This should spread uploaded images. Not sure if this is good, any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

http://highscalability.squarespace.com/blog/2012/6/20/ask-highscalability-how-do-i-organize-millions-of-images.html

There are many ways to do this as you can see, i personally recommend the SHA 1 hashing approach. The top level directory will be dependent on the first two characters that your hash generates. The second level directory will be based on the second two characters. I have found that this spreads images out pretty nicely and generates a fairly robust file structure. If you dont go with this approach you can generate GUIDs for every image and do the same thing but then you have to contend with ensuring uniqueness and all that